# Sort array by delegate

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, delegates

I want to sort an array alphabetically using a delegate. The input is

```
"m", "a", "d", "f", "h"
```

but the output is

```
 a
 a
 d
 f
 h
```

i.e. it is ordered alphabetically but the "m" is missing and with "a" doubled. What is the reason?

Source code:

```
class ArrayMethods
{
    public void sort(String[] array, t xcompare)
    {
        xcompare = compare;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1  ; i++)
        {
            array[i] = xcompare(array[i], array[i + 1]);
        }

        foreach (var a in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }

    public String compare(string p, string x)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (String.Compare(p, x) < 0)
        {
            result = p;
        }
        else
        {
            result = x;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public delegate string t(string firstString, string secondString);

class Program
{
    public static string[] names = { "m", "a", "d", "f", "h" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayMethods arrayMethods = new ArrayMethods();
        t delHandler = null;

        arrayMethods.sort(names, delHandler);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code to find out why you're not getting the expected output?

Comment: Basically, "that's not a valid sorting algorithm". Which sorting algorithm did you intend to use - and is there any reason you're not using a built-in one? I would *strongly* advise you to use more conventional names, by the way.

Comment: why are you trying to reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: You do not write a sorting algorithm.  A core bug in your code is that you overwrite an array element instead of swapping two of them, making the "m" disappear.

Comment: This is a task I find in the internet to exercise delegates. I know that there are algorithms but I want to use a delegate. Hans Passant how is the solution?

Comment: thank you Hans Passant to remark the error in my thouhts. I'm ussing now another for loop with an other array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need is to implement a sorting program using delegates, use the following code. Basically, your sorting algorithm is wrong: instead of swapping your elements you are replacing the elements.

```
class ArrayMethods
{
    public void sort(String[] array, t xcompare)
    {
        xcompare = compare;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            xcompare(array);
        }

        foreach (var a in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }

    public void compare(String[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = n; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (((IComparable)array[j - 1]).CompareTo(array[j]) > 0)
                {
                    string temp = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public delegate void t(String[] array);

class Program
{
    public static string[] names = { "m", "a", "d", "f", "h" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayMethods arrayMethods = new ArrayMethods();
        t delHandler = null;

        arrayMethods.sort(names, delHandler);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but something is wrong. the program says to me that the method compare has the wrong return type. This concerns the row   xcompare = compare;

Comment: have you changed your delegate definition? it should be as defined above could you check?

Comment: yes its all right altered. could it be that the compare method has to give back a string or something?

Comment: Compare is void here, your array sorting will happen in compare no need to return anything. Can you mark it as answer.

Comment: Always your delegate definition and callback method should have same signature. In your following post change the delegate signature. If you want compare method name to give meaningful name change it to bubblesort.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrayMethods
{
    public void sort(String[] array, t xcompare)
    {
        xcompare = compare; * here comes the error message: Error 1 "void   
        DelegateSecondT.ArrayMethods.compare(string[])" has the wrong return type.  
        (I translated the error message in english)*
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)   
        {

            xcompare(array);
        }

        foreach (var a in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

    }

    public void compare(String[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            for (int j = n; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (((IComparable)array[j - 1]).CompareTo(array[j]) > 0)
                {
                    string temp = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 public delegate string t(String[] array);

class Program
{

    public static string[] names = { "m", "a", "d", "f", "h" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayMethods arrayMethods = new ArrayMethods();
        t delHandler = null;

        arrayMethods.sort(names, delHandler);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Here your delegate declaration should be public delegate void t(String[] array); Instead public delegate string t(String[] array); Please copy the entire code from my post and run.